# Загрузка данных в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Не могу понять, почему подгружает данные в RecyclerView только один раз, т.е. получаю в формате JSON данные о 8 пользователях, но адаптер обрабатывает только один, а в цикле перебираю получаю все.

В цикле:

```
Example example = response.body();
Data data = example.getData();
List<Dialog> dialogs = data.getDialogs();
Log.i("Data", data.getPagesCount() + "-" + data.getEnd());
for (int i = 0; i < dialogs.size(); i++) {
Log.i("Data", dialogs.get(i).getFromUser().getName());
}
```

В адапторе:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Example> exampleData;

DataAdapter(List<Example> examples) {
    this.exampleData = examples;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Example example = exampleData.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(example.getData().getDialogs().get(position).getFromUser().getName());
    holder.name2.setText(example.getData().getDialogs().get(position).getFromUser().getLastAuth());
    Log.i("Data", String.valueOf(position)); // Только один раз
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (exampleData == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return exampleData.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name, name2;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        name2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name2TextView);
    }
}}
```

Вызывают

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
List<Example> mExample;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mExample = new ArrayList<>();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(mExample);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    TestServices testServices = TestServices.retrofit.create(TestServices.class);

    final Call<Example> call = testServices.getData();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mExample.addAll(Collections.singleton(response.body()));
                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
// Example example = response.body();
// Data data = example.getData();
// List<Dialog> dialogs = data.getDialogs();
// Log.i("Data", data.getPagesCount() + "-" + data.getEnd());
// for (int i = 0; i < dialogs.size(); i++) {
//   Log.i("Data", dialogs.get(i).getFromUser().getName());
// }
            } else {
                ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorBody.string(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.i("Error", "Что-то пошло не так: " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Исправил на

```
Example example = response.body();
                    Data data = example.getData();
                    List<Dialog> dialogs = data.getDialogs();
                    mExample.addAll(dialogs);
                    mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

В адаптере на

```
Dialog example = exampleData.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(example.getFromUser().getName());
        holder.name2.setText(example.getFromUser().getLastAuth());
        Log.i("Data", example.getFromUser().getName());
        Log.i("Data", example.getFromUser().getLastAuth());
```

Теперь в логе все выводится правильно, но в RecyclerView так же только один

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в адаптер объект Example - а нужно передавать список Dialog

```
mExample.addAll(Arrays.asList(response.body().getData().getDialogs()));
```

Ну и в адаптере в конструкторе принимайте:

```
private List<Dialog> dialogList;

DataAdapter(List<Dialog> dialogList) {
 this.dialogList = dialogList;
}
```

Получается что в цикле Вы правильно достаете данные (список Dialog) а в адаптер передаете объект Example которые и есть responce.

Comment: Не помогло, такой же эффект

Comment: изменил ответ..

Comment: Изменил как посоветовал @EugeneZaychenko на `Example example = response.body();
                    Data data = example.getData();
                    List<Dialog> dialogs = data.getDialogs();
                    mExample.addAll(dialogs);` Так же в адаптере добавил `Log.i("Data", example.getFromUser().getName());` что бы видеть что происходит, выводит все данные в лог как положено, но в RecyclerView`е не отображается

Comment: Не пойму, почему в логах есть получаемые данные а в RecyclerView нет? `Dialog example = exampleData.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(example.getFromUser().getName());
        holder.name2.setText(example.getFromUser().getLastAuth());
        Log.i("Data", example.getFromUser().getName());`

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Проблема решилась как подключил CardView, честно сказать странный глюк

Comment: Я скажу Вам в чем была проблема 1) проблема та что я Вам описал  2) скорее всего до подключение CardView у вашего item'a который сетится в ресайкл, разметка по высоте была match_parent из-за этого растягивалась на весь экран. Элементы были, но не влазили на экран, надо было просто прокрутить.